# How to tell Wine that I have changed CD when mounting them virtually on a netbook with no CD drive?

Tags: mount, wine

I have been trying to catch up with some of the old games from way back that are about right for my little Aspire One netbook through Wine.

I've run into a problem *Baldurs Gate,* however, which is that I can't change CD.

Obviously, I don't have a CD drive, so I have copied the CD content onto an external hard drive and I'm using a `mount` command with the loopback option to persuade the game that the CD is present. This allowed installation to work correctly and works fine to run it and to play the content from the first CD. However, when the game asks for CD2, I'm stuck.

If I mount the CD2 ISO to the CD Rom path it doesn't appear to respond, whether or not I have first unmounted CD1. When I ask Wine to show me the CD drive it contains the right data, but it seems as though whatever signal would be interpreted by Windows to mean the CD drive has been closed isn't being sent.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree and there is something else I need to do?

Comment: any luck with these solutions?

Comment: The tutorial looks like it should work, but I haven't actually managed to *make* it work yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread because I was having the same issue. This may not work for everyone, but it did for me. (I made a folder in home called /virtualdrive/Drive0) Also, I had the problem with a different game, but I think it applies.

Mount iso # 1

> sudo mount -o loop AOMG_D1.iso ~/virtualdrive/Drive0

Run game installer, hit install. It loads to 32% or something, then asks for iso # 2. Don't try to eject or unmount first iso, just use the same command to mount iso # 2. I think this creates a random drive letter and automatically maps the mount path in wine.

Mount iso # 2

> sudo mount -o loop AOMG_D2.iso ~/virtualdrive/Drive0

You should wait 5-10 seconds at this point, and it should continue the installation. If not, try pressing "OK" to the prompt about inserting next disc.

I was actually QUITE surprised this worked.

Comment: This one works over wine eject command and other tricks haha

Comment: using the ISO files with `mount` didn't work for me for some reason - the mountpoint contents stayed the same. What worked is mounting all iso files first, then running `sudo mount -o loop /dev/loop2 /run/media/johannes/FIRSTCDMOUNTPOINT`. The name of the device can be found by executing `losetup` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but I think you need to use the `wine eject` command (http://wiki.winehq.org/eject)

Comment: I get a message  "Cannot open device for drive e:" - apparently this is a feature in wine, although I couldn't quite follow why.

Comment: I wonder if this is because I have to use `sudo` to mount the drive, but if I run wine as superuser it complains because that's not the current user profile.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial that covers this here:
http://wiki.winehq.org/Infinity_Engine_Games

You might try the solution at the bottom of the page first ("AnotherAlternativeToInstall"), as it seems to require fewer steps.

There are also specific things people did to install and run in the entries at [winehq for Baldur's Gate](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=157).